# Pass GraphQL query to Apollo MockedProvider

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a small GraphQL query that I want to mock with Apollo's `MockedProvider`.

```js
export const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    getUsername: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: ({ session }) => {
        if (session.isLoggedIn) return session.username;
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
});

export default new GraphQLSchema({ query: queryType, mutation: mutationType });
```

I tried adding it to the `mocks` array, but I couldn't figure out how to convert that query to a format it accepts. My code looks something like this:

```js
const { getUsername } = queryType.getFields();
const mocks = [
  {
    request: { query: getUsername },
    result: { data: { getUsername: 'username' } }
  }
];

const app = (
  <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
    <App />
  </MockedProvider>
)
```

I tried to wrap it in gql tag, but it doesn't accept that either. How can I mock this query in my tests?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You have to first create a response for your query like this.

```
const addLanguageMock = {
  request: {
    query: Loaction_Query,
    variables: {
      name: 'हिंदी',
      iso_code: 'hin',
      name_in_english: 'hindi'
    }
  },
  result: {
    data: {}
  }
};
```

Then you can pass it like this.

> ```
>   const mocks = [addLanguageMock]
>   <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
>     <App />
>   </MockedProvider>
> ```